# Mysql Query - How get first row of each category and column and its comparison?

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query to find Which week of month is the most expensive week (week_of_month) and how much in this week 
is spent (WOM_AMT) than other weeks of month each year against each supplier

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you `max` spent per week:

```
SELECT supplier, year, week_of_month, MAX(wom_amt)
FROM table t
GROUP BY supplier, year, week_of_month;
```

Now, in order to compare this amount against the `SUM` of the rest, you can wrap this query into outer query and calculate the `SUM`, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.supplier, a.year, a.week_of_month, a.wom_amt as 'max_amount',
(SELECT SUM(wom_amt) FROM table WHERE supplier = a.supplier AND year = a.year 
AND week_of_month = a.week_of_month AND wom_amt != a.wom_amt) as 'other_amounts'
FROM (SELECT supplier, year, week_of_month, MAX(wom_amt)
    FROM table t
    GROUP BY supplier, year, week_of_month) a;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you are looking for is [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) and [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
SELECT 
    `Supplier`, 
    `Year`, 
    `Week_Of_Month`, 
    MAX(`WOM_AMT`) AS WOM_AMT
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `Supplier`, `Year`
```